# How to use spinners in android?

Tags: java, android, spinner, fill

I am new to android. I am trying to make simple unit converter. The layout contains EditText for input, two spinners (to and from), an ImageButton and EditText to display answer. 
I want to add values to spinners and when these values are selected i want to perform action.

My xml code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
tools:context=".BitsBytes" >

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/SpinnerFrom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/inputvalue"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:entries="@array/bitsbytesfrom"
    android:prompt="@string/from_prompt" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/SpinnerTo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/SpinnerFrom"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:entries="@array/bitsbytesto"
    android:prompt="@string/to_prompt" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/SpinnerFrom"
    android:layout_below="@+id/SpinnerFrom"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="To:"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="20dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Value: "
    android:textSize="20dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/inputvalue"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView6"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Enter value"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_below="@+id/inputvalue"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="From:"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
    android:text="Bits/Bytes Conversion"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textSize="25dp" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/convertButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/SpinnerTo"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:src="@drawable/btnconvert" 
    android:clickable="true"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/answer"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Answer"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/answer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="28dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

My java code:

```
package com.easy.convert;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class BitsBytes extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.bitsbytes);

    ImageButton ib = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.convertButton);
    ib.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                EditText etValue = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputvalue);
                Spinner spBitsBytesFrom = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.SpinnerFrom);
                Spinner spBitsBytesTo = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.SpinnerTo);
                String txtFromSpinner = spBitsBytesFrom.getSelectedItem().toString();
                String txtToSpinner = spBitsBytesTo.getSelectedItem().toString();
                TextView Answer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer);

                public void onClick(View v)
                {

                    if (txtFromSpinner.equals("Bits") && txtToSpinner.equals("Bytes"))
                    {
                        Double value = Double.parseDouble(etValue.getText().toString());
                        Double answer = (double) 0;
                        answer = value/8;
                        String stringAnswer = Double.toString(answer);
                        Answer.setText(stringAnswer);
                    }

                }
            });

}
}
```

I am filling the spinners using string array. I am not able to figure out whats wrong in my code because there is no error in logcat.

Comment: What *exactly* is the problem you are having?

Comment: First take all your findViewById code out of onClick and place it in onCreate. Now explain your problem?

Comment: You've done the tutorial? developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html

Comment: Nothing happens when i click on convert button.. @AtulOHolic: I tried moving all findViewById code to onCreate it is showing me this error: Cannot refer to a non-final variable txtFromSpinner inside an inner class defined in a different method. Same for other variables.

Comment: When you get such errors you should either declare your variables at class level (above onCreate() method) or declare them as final so that you can access them inside  onClick method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this,

```
 (txtFromSpinner.equals("Bits") && txtToSpinner.equals("Bytes"))
```

to

```
if((txtFromSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Bits")) && (txtToSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Bytes")))
```

this will get the text from the item selected in the spinner.

Comment: if((spBitsBytesFrom.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Bits")) && (spBitsBytesTo.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Bytes")))